# In vim Tagbar not work in modules in javascript?

Tags: javascript, vim, tagbar

i am working in vim and when i make js with `modules` then it not shown any tag.

and when i make this file with `Class` then it will show in taglist all things like below

### Class

### Method

### Function

### variables

and etc

**like my module code like something in which Tagbar not working**

```
var ENQUIRY = (function(){
      var enquiryData = {}, 
          tabTitleObj = {}, 
          screenData = {}, 
          tabContainer = $("<ul></ul>"),
          enquiryEntity = {}, 
          entityName = 'Incident',
          element = "", 
          completedEnquiryTabs = 0,
          dialogTitle = "", 
          editElement = "", 
          yesElement = " ",
          noElement = "<a href='#' class=' cancelImg' style='display:none' ><span >Cancel</span></a>";
          })();
```

**and in normal mode it will like like below an Tagbar show this variable in Tagbar list**

```
 var enquiryData = {}, 
              tabTitleObj = {}, 
              screenData = {}, 
              tabContainer = $("<ul></ul>"),
              enquiryEntity = {}, 
              entityName = 'Incident',
              element = "", 
              completedEnquiryTabs = 0,
              dialogTitle = "", 
              editElement = "", 
              yesElement = " ",
              noElement = "<a href='#' class=' cancelImg' style='display:none' ><span >Cancel</span></a>";
```

please help me to set Tagbar for modular JavaScript.

Comment: The question is unclear both with respect to what your current situation is and what your expected situation is.

Comment: i explained all things dear but its ok i am trying to improve this

Comment: Perhaps you might want to add some sample code as well.

Comment: This still doesn't clarify very well what tagbar is doing and what it is not. My guess is it should be showing both ENQUIRY & enquiryData variables. Also, the use of 'modules' is a bit confusing here, I assumed you were talking about node modules.

Comment: thanks @DhruvaSagar i think question read by a wrong person i have mention many things but its ok
here i am making module with ENQUIRY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TagBar doesn't index your code: it delegates the job to an external program like exuberant ctags or jsctags. Correctly indexing your code is thus not a TagBar problem but a ctags/jsctags problem.

If you need help with either of those you'll have to ask another, more precise, question. If possible written in a better english. Or search this site because the topic has been discused many times before.